# Python pandas cannot read excel check marks

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

What i simply need to do, is to read some xlsx files, and remove every row that contain check mark on it. So i tried that :

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
df = df[~df['Locked'].isin([stringlist])] # got several different check marks in stringlist
```

Sadly, when i tried the following, i've noticed that the above code cannot read the check marks.

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

print (df)

    Users:    Locked:

    user1     NaN
    user2     NaN
```

At the Locked column in the xlsx file,  there is check for user2. However, pandas cannot see it and still loads all the dataframe with 'NaN' values. My question is, can i solve that somehow ? In the xlsx files, that checks are small images. I don't really need to load that images like tick character, i just need to read them somehow, so i can tell python to remove that row if the cell at locked isn't 'NaN'.

Comment: I don't think pandas can read images. It will put `NaN` for those cells.

Comment: Hey @MayankPorwal . If not pandas, what else i should use ?

Comment: You can try using [`PIL`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Comment: If `stringlist` is already a list, do `df[~df['Locked'].isin(stringlist)]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding that code in the main code:

```
import win32com.client
x=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb=x.Workbooks.Open("<path_to.xlsx>")
ws=wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
for i in ws.Shapes:
    print i.TopLeftCell.Address
```

The result from the above code is :

```
$B$2
```

which let me know in which cells i got images. after that i am saving those in list, and then i drop the cells with :

```
for n in cell_list:
    a = n[3:]
    df = df.drop([a])
```

Please note that the above code isn't recognizing what the images are. In my case i got only check marks in the locked (recognized as $B from win32com), so this is working fine for me.